# I want to lock a cell in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to lock the cell A4 by VBA but it doesn't work.

here is the code:

```
Public Sub utente()
    Dim userName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Foglio1")

    userName = Application.userName
    ws.Range("A4").Value = userName
    ws.Range("A4").Locked = True
End Sub
```

im new with VBA, can anyone explain me how to lock only the cell not the entire page.

Comment: The lock works only if you set a password for your workbook.

Comment: Try adding ws.Protect command to enable the locking.

Comment: An alternative is to use "Data validation", select list and use only 1 allowable entry, this will lock the cell without the need for the sheet to be in protected mode. (Note that you can still overwrite the cell if you paste.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All cells in a worksheet are locked by default.
Protecting the sheet then applies the lock.

```
Public Sub utente()
    Dim userName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Foglio1")
    
    ws.Unprotect Password:="abc"
    ws.Cells.Locked = False 'No need to do this if cells are unlocked already.

    userName = Application.userName
    ws.Range("A4").Value = userName
    ws.Range("A4").Locked = True
    
    ws.Protect Password:="abc"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: No problem.  The `ws.Cells.Locked = False` line isn't needed if you manually go through and unlock the cells you want to remain unlocked.

Comment: @lendy The password not required `ws.Protect` and   `ws.Unprotect` is enough if you only want to assure the accidental overwrite.